# Unity3D : Unity fails to detect null objects

Tags: unity, unityscript

im instantiating an object which is gonna play the background music for my game. On the Awake() function I check if there is a gameobject with the tag "MusicPlayer" on it, and if there isn't any I instantiate a prefab (the music player prefab with the tag "MusicPlayer" on it).

Now my issue is this :

It keeps instantiating the prefabs even if there is one or more music players(objects with the "MusicPlayer" tag on them). Why is this happening ?

Here is my code :

```
var musicPrefab : Transform;

function Awake()
{
    if(GameObject.FindWithTag("MusicPlayer") == null)
    {
        Instantiate(musicPrefab,transform.position,transform.rotation);
    }
}
```

I also have a script that makes the music player not be destroyed upon the level reload. This is the script :

```
function Start()
{
    DontDestroyOnLoad (gameObject);
}
```

Thank you for your time, I hope I was clear enough.

Comment: Are you placing these script on a general purpose `GameManager` or directly on the `MusicPlayer`?  You make get some value from reading [this](http://unitypatterns.com/singletons/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ehm...

I don't know whats going on but this is what I did to fix this :

```
var musicPrefab : GameObject;
var muter : GameObject;

function Awake()
{
    if(GameObject.FindWithTag("MusicPlayer") == null)
    {
        Instantiate(musicPrefab,transform.position,transform.rotation);
        DontDestroyOnLoad (musicPrefab);
        muter = GameObject.FindWithTag("MusicPlayer");
    }

    muter = musicPrefab;
}
```

You can compare the first script with this one. I don't know how I did it but it works.

Answer (score 1):

The FindWithTag will throw an error if the Tag is not defined (or perhaps spelled wrong). I think that might have been why it did not work at first, but works now :)